# Inline SVG using React (without JSX)

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to display an in-line HTML SVG as follows:

```
<a target="blank_" href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
  <svg class="svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M19,3A2,2 0 0,1 21,5V19A2,2 0 0,1 19,21H5A2,2 0 0,1 3,19V5A2,2 0 0,1 5,3H19M18.5,18.5V13.2A3.26,3.26 0 0,0 15.24,9.94C14.39,9.94 13.4,10.46 12.92,11.24V10.13H10.13V18.5H12.92V13.57C12.92,12.8 13.54,12.17 14.31,12.17A1.4,1.4 0 0,1 15.71,13.57V18.5H18.5M6.88,8.56A1.68,1.68 0 0,0 8.56,6.88C8.56,5.95 7.81,5.19 6.88,5.19A1.69,1.69 0 0,0 5.19,6.88C5.19,7.81 5.95,8.56 6.88,8.56M8.27,18.5V10.13H5.5V18.5H8.27Z" />
  </svg>
</a>
```

As a react component without JSX. Something like:

```
let path = React.createElement('path', {d: "M19,3A2,2 0 0,1 21,5V19A2,2 0 0,1 19,21H5A2,2 0 0,1 3,19V5A2,2 0 0,1 5,3H19M18.5,18.5V13.2A3.26,3.26 0 0,0 15.24,9.94C14.39,9.94 13.4,10.46 12.92,11.24V10.13H10.13V18.5H12.92V13.57C12.92,12.8 13.54,12.17 14.31,12.17A1.4,1.4 0 0,1 15.71,13.57V18.5H18.5M6.88,8.56A1.68,1.68 0 0,0 8.56,6.88C8.56,5.95 7.81,5.19 6.88,5.19A1.69,1.69 0 0,0 5.19,6.88C5.19,7.81 5.95,8.56 6.88,8.56M8.27,18.5V10.13H5.5V18.5H8.27Z", null);
let svg = React.createElement('svg', {className: "svg" viewBox: "0 0 24 24"}, path);
let link = React.createElement('a', {target: "blank_", href="https://www.linkedin.com/"}, svg);
```

But I am having trouble getting svg's to display. Any tips on displaying inline svg's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had some typos in your script. I've fixed them up below. Feel free to do a comparison.

```js
let path = React.createElement('path', {d: "M19,3A2,2 0 0,1 21,5V19A2,2 0 0,1 19,21H5A2,2 0 0,1 3,19V5A2,2 0 0,1 5,3H19M18.5,18.5V13.2A3.26,3.26 0 0,0 15.24,9.94C14.39,9.94 13.4,10.46 12.92,11.24V10.13H10.13V18.5H12.92V13.57C12.92,12.8 13.54,12.17 14.31,12.17A1.4,1.4 0 0,1 15.71,13.57V18.5H18.5M6.88,8.56A1.68,1.68 0 0,0 8.56,6.88C8.56,5.95 7.81,5.19 6.88,5.19A1.69,1.69 0 0,0 5.19,6.88C5.19,7.81 5.95,8.56 6.88,8.56M8.27,18.5V10.13H5.5V18.5H8.27Z"}, null);
let svg = React.createElement('svg', {className: "svg", viewBox: "0 0 24 24"}, path);
let link = React.createElement('a', {target: "_blank", href:"https://www.linkedin.com/"}, svg);

ReactDOM.render(link, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I had tried on a couple separate occasions but could not get it to work (i thought i was misunderstanding something) - thanks so much!

Comment: Also, you can accomplish the same thing without using ```createElement``` at all.  JSX supports SVG elements the same as HTML.  You may need to camelCase certain properties (e.g. fill-rule, etc.), but otherwise you can basically copy/paste from an HTML file.